Getting request data in nghttp2 C server
I am not able to find any good guide to this and I'm not an expert on pure C. I am using nghttp2 and am sending curl requests to test out the logic. I need to grab the request body and process it further but I'm having issues with that. In the nghttp2 server tutorial they are saving header data in the custom struct called http2_stream_data. I saw some other people in github reuse that structure to also grab the request body. It looks like they are defining a callback using nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_data_chunk_recv_callback and grabbing a pointer. I tried the same thing but it didn't work.
I've been trying to get the request body like this:
typedef struct http2_stream_data {
  struct http2_stream_data *prev, *next;
  char *request_path;
  char *request_method;
  char *data;
  size_t len;
  int32_t stream_id;
  int fd;
} http2_stream_data;
static int on_data_chunk_recv_callback(nghttp2_session *session,
                                       uint8_t flags, int32_t stream_id,
                                       const uint8_t *data, size_t len,
                                       void *user_data) {
  http2_stream_data *stream_data;
  char *body;
  int body_len;
  stream_data =
          nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data(session, stream_id);
  body = stream_data->data;
  body_len = stream_data->len;
  for(int i = 0; i < body_len; i++) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%c", data[i]);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  return 0;
}

There's probably something wrong in the way I map the data, I can't figure this part out.
